# ng-switch button inside switch steatment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

switch button inside switch statement but It only works when It's outside switch statement Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController as LC">
    <div ng-switch on="view.name">

        <div ng-switch-default>
            <input type="email" required>
            <input type="password" required>
            <button type="submit" class="form-submit">Login</button>
            <a href="#" ng-click="view.name='forgotpassword'">Forgot Your Password</a>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="forgotpassword">
            <input type="email" equired>
            <button type="submit" class="form-submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, ModalService) {
    $scope.view = {
        name: ''
    };
});
```

Comment: Your code is working... When clicking on `Forgot password`, it display the forgotpassword div

Answer (score 1):

I just add outside div and add `ng-hide`

```
<a href="#" ng-hide="view.name === 'forgotpassword'" ng-click="view.name = 'forgotpassword'">Forgot Your Password</a>
```